# how can I display loading status of download of pdf in iOS

Tags: ios

I have an application where at one point the user navigates to a PDF stored on my website.  I am using this code to display the pdf

```
   NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/test.pdf"];
   NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];

   [webView loadRequest:myRequest];

   [window addSubview: myWebView];
```

and it is working fine, however it takes 1-2 seconds to actually download and display the pdf.

Right now the screen is just blank during that time and I was wondering if there is a way to display the "spinny loading indicator thing" (also what is this called) and how do I determine the status of the download... is there a method called when the download has been started or when it is halfway? Can I get a percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol provides some basic hooks for tracking when a request has started and stopped.  In your view controller you could do something similar to the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.webView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // Start spinner
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // Stop spinner
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    // Stop spinner, show error
}
```

To show the percent progress, you will have to do something more complex, since you need information such as number of bytes expected and number of bytes received.  This requires you to download manually using a `NSURLConnection` and its delegate.  The flow would look like the following:

1. Make sure your server returns the `Content-Length` header for the PDF file.  If it doesn't you will never be able to know how much of the file remains.
2. Use a new instance of `NSURLConnection` for your request with a delegate that can handle the following steps.
3. When the response header completes, you will get `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` which lets you retrieve the `Content-Length` header. You will use this as the total part of the progress fraction.  Create a new file you will write your PDF to.
4. When data comes in, you will receive `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`.  Write the data to the file and keep track of the total length of data you've received for your fraction: `percent complete = total data received / total data expected`
5. When the file completes, you will receive `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`.  Use this to close the file, update the progress to 100%.
6. Convert the file path into a file URL, create a new `NSURLRequest` and feed that into the web view.

Obviously, this can be a pain and there are other considerations so if this is what you're looking for you should consider a third-party library.  With AFNetworking, you can download a file using an output stream and track the progress:

```
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:@"download.pdf" append:NO];
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    float progress = ((float)totalBytesRead) / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    // Do something.
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) in conjunction with a progress HUD such as [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

Or, use [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) and leverage the delegate method

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data`

And track data received / total data.